# Call function inside AndroidView or AndroidViewBinding Composable

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-view

How to call functions inside AndroidView or AndroidViewBinding composable?
In the old view system if I needed to update a TextView and other things in multiple places I simply created a function like that:

```
private fun updateViews(value1: Int, value2: Int) = with(binding) {
    timelineTextView.text = "$value1, $value2"
    ... A lot of other stuff

}
```

How is that possible when using the AndroidViewBinding Composable?

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(){
    AndroidViewBinding(ActivityPlayBinding::inflate) {
        playButton.setOnClickListener {
            updateViews(value1, value2)
        }

        playButton2.setOnClickListener {
            updateViews(value1, value2)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I call that `updateViews` function in Compose?
Simply putting the content of updateViews function where the function gets called feels really bad cause that causes a lot of duplicate code. But I cant seem to find the right way to do it…

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid duplicating the code in `updateViews`, you can do that a couple of ways:

- Create `fun updateViews()` anywhere you like, and pass everything it needs as a parameter (that is, you need to pass the binding to `updateViews` along with the other parameters).
- Create `fun updateViews()` inside the `AndroidViewBinding` lambda, and call it as normal. It will have access to the binding, just as the rest of the lambda does. For example:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(){
    AndroidViewBinding(ActivityPlayBinding::inflate) {
        private fun updateViews(value1: Int, value2: Int) = with(binding) {
            timelineTextView.text = "$value1, $value2"
            ... A lot of other stuff
        }

        playButton.setOnClickListener {
            updateViews(value1, value2)
        }
        
        playButton2.setOnClickListener {
            updateViews(value1, value2)
        }
    }
}
```